# How can I emulate key presses on Vim startup?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When I run vim, the NerdTree plugin opens a project explorer. I achieved this by adding the following line to my `.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

It opens two buffers but unfortunately I need to press `^W^W` each time because the active buffer is the left one, where the NerdTree is located.

How can I make vim emulate these key presses on startup?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to give Vim keypresses in a command. The general way is to use the `:normal` command, which in this case would be

```
:execute "normal \<C-W>\<C-W>"
```

where the `:execute` command is needed to expand the control characters. For normal commands that begin with Ctrl-W, however, the `:wincmd` command can be simpler to use, e.g.,

```
:wincmd w
```

where in this case I've taken advantage of the fact that Ctrl-W Ctrl-W and Ctrl-W w do the same thing. Your autocommand would then be

```
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd w
```

See

```
:help :normal
:help :wincmd
:help CTRL-W_w
```

Comment: I had a script from somewhere that had `execute 'normal 1<c-W>_'` that didn't work on my vim setup. Swapping the single-quotes for doubles and adding the `\` finally got it running.

Comment: what's the difference between `:execute "normal \<C-W>\<C-W>"` and `:silent execute "normal \<C-W>\<C-W>"` ?